# how does java treat octal and decimal number

Tags: java

I am not able to understand how java stores the value specified as octal and hexadecimal value.i need an explanation for the output of the following code snippet.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main ( String args[] )
    {

        int a = 10 , b = 017 , c = 0X3A ; 
        System.out.println( a + " " + b + " " + c) ; 
    } 
}
```

The output produced by this code is

```
10 15 58
```

a detailed explanation on the output would be of great help.Thanks in advance

Comment: Internal implementation of numbers is allways the same. bin / hex /octa can be external presentation. In diffrent words: an number doesnt know, was born from bin / oct /hex / dec constant

Comment: `017` octal is 15 dec. `3A` hex is 58 dec. What specifically is confusing you?

Comment: It is unclear what you're asking. Please develop.

Comment: What is there to explain? 15 decimal is 15 decimal, 017 octal is 15 decimal, 3A hex is 58 decimal. The compller does all these conversions during compilation. Java does *not* store anything as octal or hex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically if an assigned integer value begins with 0,it is considered to be an octal value and if the assigned integer value begins with 0x it is taken as hexadecimal value.  Decimal system is used for programming as it is easy to comprehend. In java,
'println' outputs a single value after converting the value using the appropriate 'toString' method.By default toString() does not pass any radix value explicitly and processes value as radix of type decimal.

[Refer source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toString)

As for your snippet, the following illustration will show how you arrive at the obtained result.

1. **a=10** is a decimal value. Therefore it is printed as such.
2. **b=017** is an octal value as it begins with '0'.Octal to decimal conversion takes place before the result is printed.

   **CONVERSION:**

   (8^0) * 7 + (8^1) * 1 = 7+8 = 15
3. **c=0X3A** is a hexadecimal value as it begins with '0X'. Hexadecimal to decimal conversion takes place.

   **CONVERSION:**

   (16^0) * A + (16^1) * 3 = 10+48 =58 [since [A-F] in hexadecimal system indicates values [10-15]

Thus we have **a=10 b=15 and c=58**

**NOTE:** *If you need to print hexa or octal value as such you can change the format specifier.*

```
**System.out.printf("%o %x",b,c);**
```

**OUTPUT: 3a 17**

Comment: The conversions happen at compile time.

Comment: thanks a lot .. this is the explanation i expected